# Can Environment.getExternalStorageState() be not mounted on Android ICS?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-sdcard

I have the following code from previous projects for Android 2.1-2.3 that checks if SD card is mounted and writable or not.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkSDCard();
}

private void checkSDCard(){
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SD card mounted and writable.");
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sdcard mounted readonly");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "sdcard state: " + state);
        mWarningSdCardDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Warning")
                .setMessage(R.string.warning_sdcard_message)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok),
                        mWarningSdCardDialogCliclListener)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();
        mWarningSdCardDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Now I'm working on projects that will be launched on Android ICS devices. I found that Android ICS device cannot be simply connected to computer like USB Mass Storage.
My question is: have my old code any sense now? Is SD card always mounted and writable on Android ICS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, still makes sense. There are devices (e.g. the Nexus S) that allow USB mass storage mode with ICS and JB.